# Proving if $|a|_p=1$ then $a$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, p-adic-number-theory

I decided to take a look $p$-adic integers. I am trying to show that
$$a \in \mathbb{Z}_p \text{ is invertible if and only if } |a|_p=1$$
where
$$|x|_p= \left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
   p^{-n} & \mbox{if } x\neq0 \\
   0 & \mbox{if } x=0
  \end{array}
 \right.$$
where $n=\min\{ m \geq 0 : x_n\neq0\}$ and 
$$x=x_0+x_1p+x_2p^2+\cdots.$$

The "forward" direction is very easy. I am having trouble going backwards. What I have been trying to do is construct the inverse of $a$ and tentatively I am calling the inverse of $a$ as $b=b_0+b_1p+\cdots.$ I have that $b_0=a_0^{-1}$, obviously, and as $|a|_p=1$ it follows $a_0\neq0$ so it has an inverse modulo $p$, which was needed. My goal is to show:
$$\text{For all $m\geq0,$ } 1=\left[\left(\sum_{i=0}^m a_ip^i\right)\left(\sum_{i=0}^m b_ip^i\right)\right]     \mod{p^{m+1}} \qquad \text{(1)}$$
I am doing this on my own and have been having some trouble formulating (to me at least) good sounding ways to express what I need to prove, in terms of lemmas and things to establish $(1)$.

Roughly, I have been trying to show: $Lemma$. Given $b_0,b_1,\cdots,b_k \in \{0,1,\cdots,(p-1)\}$ which satisfy
$$1=\left[\left(\sum_{i=0}^k a_ip^i\right)\left(\sum_{i=0}^k b_ip^i\right)\right]     \mod{p^{k+1}} \qquad\text{(2)}$$
I can find a $b_{k+1}$ which makes the following statement true:
$$1=\left[\left(\sum_{i=0}^{k+1} a_ip^i\right)\left(\sum_{i=0}^{k+1} b_ip^i\right)\right]     \mod{p^{k+2}}\qquad\text{(3)}$$
This is what I have been working with and finding a $b_1$ was not difficult, I chose $b_1 \in \{0,1,\cdots,(p-1)\}$ with $b_1 \equiv -a_1a_0^{-2}\mod p$, which I found to be equivalent to kind of case of $k=0$ for the Lemma. I was trying to do this by induction but I've found kind of a mess and there is a statement I need to be true that I am guessing it not generally true, namely that $g\equiv1\mod p^k$ means $g\equiv1\mod p^{k+1}$, at least that would help me out. I don't think this is true at all in general as there is the counterexample of $126\equiv1\mod 5^3$ but $126\equiv 126\not\equiv 1 \mod 5^4$. Maybe there are more conditions that need to be put on this $g$. Anyways, is there another way I can go about doing this?

Sorry for the long typing, it may or may not help to give an idea of what I am trying to do etc..Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessary to compute the actual digits of the inverse, only to show it exists. Your method of argument though becomes important when dealing with Hensel's lemma in the near future.

Since $p\nmid x$ it's clear that $x$ is invertible mod $p^k$ for each $k\ge0$. Let $a_k$ be a sequence of integers which are inverses for $x$ mod $p^k$. Can you show $(a_k)$ is a Cauchy sequence? This implies that it converges to some $a\in{\bf Z}_p$, and you can subsequently show that $ax=1$ in ${\bf Z}_p$. Hints:

- $|x|_p=1\implies |a_n-a_m|_p=|a_nx-a_mx|_p$
- $a_nx\equiv 1\equiv a_mx$ mod $p^n$ when $n\le m$
- $ax\equiv a_kx\equiv 1$ mod $p^k$

If you want, you can show that $a_n\equiv a_m\bmod p^n$ when $n\le m$; this shows that the "digits" of $a_n$ are only being added to; the "initial segments" of digits are never altered.

I am assuming you have constructed ${\bf Z}_p$ as the inverse limit of ${\bf Z}/p^n{\bf Z}$, or as ${\bf Z}[T]/(T-p)$, both routes quickly yielding permission for unique $p$-adic expansions of all $p$-adic integers and continuous ring quotient maps ${\bf Z}_p\to{\bf Z}/p^k{\bf Z}$ for all $k\ge0$.

Since ${\bf Z}_p$ is an integral domain, it has a fraction field, denoted ${\bf Q}_p$. It can be seen that the relation $|a/b|_p=|a|_p/|b|_p$ allows the $p$-adic valuation to be extended to all of ${\bf Q}_p$. From there we may show that ${\bf Q}_p\cong{\bf Z}_p[p^{-1}]$ so all $p$-adic numbers have $p$-adic expansions. Alternatively, we could have defined ${\bf Q}_p$ to be the metric completion of $\bf Q$ with respect to the $p$-adic metric.

If we have ${\bf Q}_p$ available as a valued field, the proof is much quicker: $|x|_p=1$ implies $|x^{-1}|_p=1$ implies $x^{-1}\in{\bf Z}_p$ implies $x$ is invertible in ${\bf Z}_p$.

Comment: Thank you I will see if I can work through the details and finish the proof, thanks very much!

Comment: Each $a_k$ is uniquely determined, if I understand this correctly, as $x\mod{p^k}=x_0+x_1p+\cdots+x_{k-1}p^{k-1}$ which has $\gcd(x\mod{p^k},p^k)=1$ so the inverse is unique? I am a little unsure sometimes as I don't know if I have adequately defined all these operations. I gave definitions for them, for example, to $x\mod{p^k}$ for $x \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ as I am just used to using $\mod{n}$ for integers, sorry if this doesn't sound right. I am still working on this though ;) *edit* So each $a_k\in\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the base $p$ representation for the inverse which lives in $\{0,1,\cdots,p^k-1\}$?

Comment: @Wishingwell The residue of $x$ mod $p$ is invertible implies that the residue of $x$ mod $p^k$ is invertible for any $k$. (Note that $|x|_p=1$ tells us that the first digit of $x$'s canonical $p$-adic representation is nonzero, and this first digit is congruent to $x$'s residue mod $p$.) Thus for each $k$ we can choose $a_k$ to be an integer in $\bf Z$ (or in ${\bf Z}_p$, it doesn't really matter) such that $a_kx\equiv 1$ mod $p^k$. We can think of each $a_k$ as an approximation of $x^{-1}$ "up to $p^k$ accuracy."

Comment: We can arrange for $a_k$ to be in $\{0,1,\cdots,p^k-1\}$ by forcing $a_k$ to be the *least positive integer* congruent to the inverse of $x$ mod $p^k$, but this is artificial and unnecessary. We only need the $a_k$ to converge to an inverse to $x$ mod every power of $p$, i.e. an inverse to $x$ in ${\bf Z}_p$.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you can construct the inverse of
$$x=x_0+x_1p+x_2p^2+\cdots$$
by using the usual method of (multiplicatively) inverting a power series, where the algebra is carried out mod $p$. In the book "Tables of Integrals, Series, and Products" by Gradshteyn and Ryzhik (1980 Academic Press), there is a formula for division of one power series by another which, when specialized to the numerator being simply $1$, gives the reciprocal of a series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_kx^k$ as $(1/a_0)\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_kx^k$ where for $n>0$
$$c_n+\frac{1}{a_0}\sum_{k=1}^nc_{n-k}a_k.$$
(I'm pretty sure $c_0=1$ in this, though that wasn't stated in the reference.)
This allows successive determination of the coefficients of the inverse.

There is an interesting explicit formula for $c_n$ which (in this case where the numerator series is $1$) gives the value of $c_n$ in terms of a multiple of a band matrix. Let $M$ denote the $n \times n$ band matrix having 0's above the superdiagonal, and the numbers $a_0,a_1,\cdots a_n$ as band constants for respectively the superdiagonal, the main diagonal, the subdiagonal, etc. until the last term $a_n$ appears in the lower left of $M$ (a diagonal of length 1). Then the formula is
$$c_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{a_0^n}|M|,$$where the bars on $M$ mean determinant.

Since this expression seems to hold for inverting formal polynomials over any field, it should work in the $p$ adic case. [Of course your $x_k$ are here the $a_k$ and your $p^k$ become the $x^k$ in the series inversion formula.]

NOTE: I now agree with a comment by user1 that this method doesn't work well to give the inverse. For one thing there is the matter of carrying in the p adics, so that even using the integer $|M|$ in a given digit would involve spilling it over to the next higher sequence of powers of $p$; one would start at the low end for this and it would be tedious. The presence of negative signs may also be a problem. Finally the division by $a_0^n$ would entail getting that reciprocal as a p adic and multiplying through.

For these reasons I'll likely delete this answer, unless someone thinks it can be rescued somehow.

Another comment by anon gives exactly what is happening here. The above method does give *a* representation of the inverse, but not the canonical one in which the digits are in $\{0,1,...,p-1\}$. What the power series inverse gives, after the variable is replaced by $p$, is a series whose coefficients are ordinary (integer) fractions, which does represent an inverse but is very inconvenient to put into the canonical form.

Comment: The difference between p-adic integers and power series is that you have to have the coefficients of the p-adic integer between 0 and p-1 while the coefficients of a power series merely have to be elements of the ring. The formula given for c_n does not take this into account. On the other hand, this does establish the *existence* of an inverse.

Comment: The coefficients are in the field $\mathbb{Z}_p$, and the coefficients of a power series, if one wants to invert it, must be in a field. It seems the inversion process only involves the usual operations of arithmetic, including division (which is OK in the field $\mathbb{Z}_p$).

Comment: I should have left my comment unedited. I think what happens when you carry out the multiplication is that you get zeros by having multiples of p for the coefficients. However, in p-adics that means that you carry it, while in a power series ring over $\mathbb Z_p$ no carrying would occur.

Comment: @user1 : I agree with your last comment (+1 on it) and have added to my answer what I think summarizes the objection. (I may end up deleting that answer...)

Comment: As this method is valid over ${\bf Q}((T))$, it will be valid in ${\bf Q}_p$ for the same reasons basically. However, although it will yield *a* valid representation of the inverse, it does not yield the canonical $p$-adic digital representation. The gadgets ${\bf F}_p[[T]]$ and ${\bf Z}_p$ are markedly different beasts (I highly advise against using Z_p to denote finite fields in p-adic contexts), notably in "carrying," although there are mysterious number/function-field analogies. Compare: $(2)\cdot2^0+(2)\cdot2^1$ equals $6$ but is not the base-$2$ representation of $6$.

Comment: @anon Well put (+1 for comment) and now included in answer.